# Nginx 1.24, PHP files are downloaded instemde of serving them

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-web-app-service

I use Azure App Services on our webservers. Last week they updated their nginx image to 1.24 and files are downloaded now instead of serving them.

Is anything changed since last versions?

I tried different solutions of nginx configs with the same problem nut none of them worked.

I got this nginx configuration that worked before the update:

```
server {
  #proxy_cache cache;
  #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080;
  root /home/site/wwwroot/public;
  index  index.php;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com;  
  port_in_redirect off;
  client_max_body_size 128M;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

  if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
      break;
  }

  location / {            
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
      root   /html/;
  }
  
  # Disable .git directory
  location ~ /\.git {
      deny all;
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
  }

  # Disable htaccess access
  location ~ /\. {
      deny all;
  }
  
  # Caching
  location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|mp3|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|woff2|woff)$ {
      expires 1M;
      access_log off;
      # max-age must be in seconds
      add_header Cache-Control "max-age=2629746, public";
  }

  # CSS and Javascript
  location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
      expires 1y;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31556952, public";
  }

  # PHP
  location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 300; 
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Change `location ~ /` to `location /`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you, i tried changing it (updated my question) but it is still not working. Still downloaded as files.